# Gathering results of methods in one List with Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

So I am trying to 
I am defining the sets with `is_a(b, a), is_a(c, a)`, which for simplicity would look visually something like this:

```
      a
  b       c
d   e    f  g
```

I want to give in the list `[b, c]` and as a result get the list `[d, e, f, g]`

At the moment when I give in a `node` or a variable, then it can find everything that is underneath it with this method:

```
find_nodes(Root, Root) :-
    \+ is_a(_, Root).
find_nodes(Root, X) :-
    is_a(Node, Root),
    find_nodes(Node, X).
```

Which when run gives me the result I need :

```
?- find_nodes(b, X).
X = d.
X = e.
```

But it is not in a list, so I have tried :

```
?- all_nodes([b, c], X).

all_nodes([], _).
all_nodes([H|T], [R|Res]):-
    findall(L, find_nodes(H, L), R),
    all_nodes(T, Res).
```

Which gives me - `X = [[d, e], [f, g]|_4040]`, which consists of lists within lists, but I need just 1 list, that would be `X = [d, e, f, g]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Like @lurker said `findall` returns a list and adding list to a list will give the result I get right now.

The one thing I also tried was using:

```
all_nodes([], _).
all_nodes([H|T], [R|Res]):-
    find_nodes(H, R),
    all_nodes(T, Res).
```

But well that one does not work either because It only gives me 1 element, which in this case is `d` and then `f`.

Comment: `findall(...)` has a list as its third argument. So when you call `findall(L, find_nodes(H, L), R)`. `R` is a list. So `[R|Res]` is a list whose first element is itself a list, `R`. Your other issue is your base case. `all_nodes([], _)` says that all nodes of an empty list is anything you want since `_` is an anonymous variable. It can be anything.

Comment: @lurker `all_nodes([], _)` didnt really know what else to put there, probably `[]` could also work. But how can I do it without using `findall` because when i do it without and call the function recursively while replacing `findall` to just `find_nodes` then it takes only the `d` and goes to the next head.

Comment: Well, `_` does not work because it really does mean that your rule says, *finding the nodes for the empty list is anything* is a successful result, which obviously isn't logical. `[]` would be more logical, would it not? Isn't the result of finding all nodes in an empty tree an empty list specifically?

Comment: You can use `findall`. You just can't directly use the result the way you are trying to use it. You would need to concatenate the result to your current list of known nodes.

Comment: SWI Prolog also has `append(ListOfLists, List)` you can check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the de facto standard `findall/4` (*) predicate to solve the problem. This predicate is a variant of the standard `findall/3` predicate that allows passing a tail for the list of solutions collected by the predicate. For example:

```
?- findall(N, (N=1; N=2; N=3), L, [4,5]).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

In the following solution, I have renamed predicates and variables for clarity and modified your node leaf predicate:

```
is_a(a, b).
is_a(a, c).

is_a(b, d).
is_a(b, e).

is_a(c, f).
is_a(c, g).

leaf(Leaf, Leaf) :-
    \+ is_a(Leaf, _).
leaf(Node, Leaf) :-
    is_a(Node, Child),
    leaf(Child, Leaf).

all_nodes([], []).
all_nodes([Node| Nodes], Leaves):-
    findall(Leaf, leaf(Node, Leaf), Leaves, Tail),
    all_nodes(Nodes, Tail).
```

Sample calls:

```
?- all_nodes([b, c], X).
X = [d, e, f, g].

?- all_nodes([a], X).
X = [d, e, f, g].

?- all_nodes([b], X).
X = [d, e].
```

(*) It's a built-in predicate in GNU Prolog, JIProlog, Lean Prolog, O-Prolog, SICStus Prolog, SWI-Prolog, XSB, and YAP (possibly others).

Comment: With this method if I am calling the leaf node `all_nodes([d, e], X)` then it returns `X = [d, e]`, is there a way to not return the nodes that were called, even if they are leaves?.

Comment: Try modifying the `findall/4` goal argument to `(leaf(Node, Leaf), Node \== Leaf)`.

Comment: Yes, it does. Likely you made a typo modifying the `findall/4` **goal** argument. You want `findall(Leaf, (leaf(Node, Leaf), Node \== Leaf), Leaves, Tail)`. With this change your get `L = []` for the query `all_nodes([d, e], L)`.